# How can i navigate directly towards a certain section of a man page just from using the terminal?

Tags: man

I want to know what the `-fix--missing` argument does in the command below

For example:

```
man apt-get update -fix--missing
```

Now if i type the command as it is above, it will be the same thing as typing man apt-get. Then i have to type `/-fix--missing` while I'm in the man page and hit enter to jump to `-fix--missing`

Is there any faster way where i can just type one command and directly from the terminal and jump to the `-fix--missing` section of the man page? or is this not possible.

Comment: Or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302740/query-linux-man-page-for-certain-flag

Comment: Don't forget https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/96095/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18087/5132 , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/477084/5132 . (-:

Answer (score 0):

You might abuse the `LESS` variable, assuming that you are using `less` as a pager.
You can use this as the basis of your own function or script.

```
# sman, optionally search a man page.
sman(){
  case $# in
   (0|1) exec man "$@" ;;   
   (*) eval LASTARG="\$$#" ; exec LESS="-p$LASTARG" man "$1" ;;
  esac
}
```

If you pass it more than one argument it will use the final one as a pattern to search for. For this to be a serious command it should at least parse the options being passed.